# How to send a pitch bend MIDI message using arcore?

Tags: arduino-leonardo, midi

I'm new to MIDI and started playing with an Arduino Leonardo and [arcore](https://github.com/rkistner/arcore).
Based on the example code, I can easily send `noteOn/noteOff/controlChange` messages, but I can't seem to send a pitch bend message.

Having a look at [this table](http://www.onicos.com/staff/iz/formats/midi-event.html):

```
0xE0    Chan 1 Pitch wheel range    Pitch wheel LSB (0-127) Pitch wheel MSB (0-127)
    0xE1    Chan 2 Pitch wheel range    Pitch wheel LSB (0-127) Pitch wheel MSB (0-127)
    0xE2    Chan 3 Pitch wheel range    Pitch wheel LSB (0-127) Pitch wheel MSB (0-127)
    0xE3    Chan 4 Pitch wheel range    Pitch wheel LSB (0-127) Pitch wheel MSB (0-127)
    0xE4    Chan 5 Pitch wheel range    Pitch wheel LSB (0-127) Pitch wheel MSB (0-127)
    0xE5    Chan 6 Pitch wheel range    Pitch wheel LSB (0-127) Pitch wheel MSB (0-127)
    0xE6    Chan 7 Pitch wheel range    Pitch wheel LSB (0-127) Pitch wheel MSB (0-127)
    0xE7    Chan 8 Pitch wheel range    Pitch wheel LSB (0-127) Pitch wheel MSB (0-127)
    0xE8    Chan 9 Pitch wheel range    Pitch wheel LSB (0-127) Pitch wheel MSB (0-127)
    0xE9    Chan 10 Pitch wheel range   Pitch wheel LSB (0-127) Pitch wheel MSB (0-127)
    0xEA    Chan 11 Pitch wheel range   Pitch wheel LSB (0-127) Pitch wheel MSB (0-127)
    0xEB    Chan 12 Pitch wheel range   Pitch wheel LSB (0-127) Pitch wheel MSB (0-127)
    0xEC    Chan 13 Pitch wheel range   Pitch wheel LSB (0-127) Pitch wheel MSB (0-127)
    0xED    Chan 14 Pitch wheel range   Pitch wheel LSB (0-127) Pitch wheel MSB (0-127)
    0xEE    Chan 15 Pitch wheel range   Pitch wheel LSB (0-127) Pitch wheel MSB (0-127)
    0xEF    Chan 16 Pitch wheel range   Pitch wheel LSB (0-127) Pitch wheel MSB (0-127)
```

I've tried to send a message like so:

```
MIDIEvent pitchwheel = {0xe0, 127,127};
MIDIUSB.write(pitchwheel);
```

but this didn't work and I'm not sure what I'm missing/doing wrong.

Any hints/tips will be helpful.

Comment: Please show the working code to send a note-on message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

arcore creator Ralf Kistner provided the [answer](https://github.com/rkistner/arcore/issues/19):

```
// The pitch bend value is a 14-bit number (0-16383). 0x2000 (8192) is the default / middle value.

// First byte is the event type (0x0E = pitch bend change).
// Second byte is the event type, combined with the channel.
// Third byte is the 7 least significant bits of the value.
// Fourth byte is the 7 most significant bits of the value.
void pitchBendChange(byte channel, int value) {
  byte lowValue = value & 0x7F;
  byte highValue = value >> 7;
  MIDIEvent event = {0x0E, 0xE0 | channel, lowValue, highValue};
  MIDIUSB.write(event);
}
```